# How do I use 2 or more textures with different positions and texCoords?

Tags: javascript, webgl

When learning the topic from [Webgl-2-textures](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2-textures.html), found that the two textures shared same `a_positions` and `a_texCoord`, they displayed as the same size on the screen by using one `drawArrays` call. 
Is that possible to have different `a_position` and `a_texCoord`, but still could have the two images processed like: (suppose the `u_image0` is the background, and the `u_image1` is the front image which could have screen effect with the background as follows.)

```
precision mediump float;

// our textures
uniform sampler2D u_image0;
uniform sampler2D u_image1;

// the texCoords passed in from the vertex shader.
varying vec2 v_texCoord0;
varying vec2 v_texCoord1;

void main() {
   vec4 color0 = texture2D(u_image0, v_texCoord0);
   vec4 color1 = texture2D(u_image1, v_texCoord1);
   gl_FragColor = color0 * color1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to have different positions since WebGL only draws one pixel at a time. There is only one `gl_Position` to set.

It is possible to have different texture coordinates for each texture, either compute different texture coords in your fragment shader. For example

```
   vec4 color0 = texture2D(u_image0, v_texCoord0);
   vec4 color1 = texture2D(u_image1, v_texCoord0 * 2.0);
```

Now the second image is using different texture coordinates. That example might be silly but the point is it's your code. You can put any math their you want.

```
   uniform vec2 offset1;
   uniform vec2 offset2;
   uniform vec2 scale1;
   uniform vec2 scale2;

   vec4 color0 = texture2D(u_image0, v_texCoord0 * scale1 + offset1);
   vec4 color1 = texture2D(u_image1, v_texCoord0 * scale2 + offset2);
```

Otherwise you can also make a vertex shader that passes in different texture coordinates for each texture.

```
attribute vec2 texcoord0;
attribute vec2 texcoord1;

varying vec2 v_texCoord0;
varying vec2 v_texCoord1;

void main() {
  v_texcoord0 = v_texCoord0;
  v_texcoord1 = v_texCoord1;
  ...
}
```

In the same way as above what math you include is up to you. Add an offset, a scale, or a full matrix or whatever you want.

It's common to allow a full matrix.

```
  vec2 uv = (some4x4Matrix * vec4(texcoord, 0, 1)).xy;
```

This lets you translate (offset), scale, and even rotate the texture coordinates.

Here's [an article that uses that style](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-drawimage.html)